# application with game center authentication

Tags: ios, game-center

I am a new Apple developer. For one of my games, I am planning to use Game Center for authentication. But yet I am not a paid developer.

Is there a way I can test my app wit game center, before I register as a "paid developer"??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to test Game Center, In-App Purchase or Push Notifications without iPhone Developer Program account. You need signed provisioning profiles for all these features to authenticate with Apple's servers, and you don't have those profiles or a certificate to sign them without the paid account.